# Limit ordinals vs. Points at infinity

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, ordinals, projective-geometry

The **[point at infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity)** $\infty$ makes $\mathbb{R}$ into a topological circle, i.e. into the  real projective space $\mathbb{R}P$: $\infty$ enhances the original structure ($\mathbb{R}$) and makes it into another structure (not ordered anymore).

In a similar setting the first **[limit ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal)** $\omega$ enhances the original structure ($\mathbb{N}$) and makes it into another structure (still ordered).

Projective spaces are at the heart of [algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Projective_spaces_in_algebraic_geometry) while limit ordinals are at the heart of [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal).

Both concepts - the point at infinity $\infty\ $  and the first limit ordinal $\omega$ - and their respective roles (played in their resp. theories) are not too hard to grasp, if taken each of its own.

For the outsider/novice they "feel" strongly related: "(the) something at infinity".

(For the visually inclined there is a strong and striking resemblance between the symbols $\omega$ and $\infty$ [= a two-sided $\omega$].)

Especially for the outsider/novice it may be difficult to comprehend the "deep" connection between these two concepts and their respective roles - if there is any.

> If there **is** such a "deep" connection: How can it be comprehended in
>   the most "easiest" way?
>
> If there is **no** such "deep" connection: How can it be comprehended why this was a (conceptual) illusion?

Comment: I think that the only connection I can see is actually in the sense of compactification. Namely, the point in infinity is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$; a limit ordinal $\alpha$ is the one-point compactification of the *set* of ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila's comment is spot-on. The one point compactification is perhaps the most general way of talking about adding a point at infinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Asaf's comment, any ordinal number $\alpha$ can be made into a topological space by giving it with the topology generated by open intervals $(\beta,\gamma)$.  This is called the order topology on $\alpha$. In this topology, the limit points are just the limit ordinals.

This space is compact if $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal ($\alpha = \beta+1$ for some $\beta$) but not if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal (e.g., $\alpha = \omega$.)
If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal then the one-point compactification of the order topology on $\alpha$ is homeomorphic to the order topology on $\alpha+1$ via the map that fixes the elements of $\alpha$ and maps the point at infinity to the point $\alpha$ itself.